# How to count pairs of cells in alternate rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am preparing a weekly time-table for my school which looks like the following

[image]

The even rows contains course names, whereas the odd rows contain the teacher initials. Observe that a same paper is taken by more than one teacher (e.g., `C10 C11` and `G10 G11`). I need to count the *total number of classes per course per teacher* in a week. Please help me to achieve that.

My efforts so far have been very inefficient.

[image]

I calculated the formula in `B71` for each row in the entire time-table and added all the quantities in `B70`. However I need to have a comprehensive list of all courses with divisions for all teachers. I am not being able to generate that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I assume your time table layout is fixed. The easiest way would be to create a second table/sheet where you have all the data in “normalized” structure:  e.g. column A for the weekday, B for time, C for Part, D for course name, E for teacher, etc.

Comment: First row/line of this new table: e.g. A2: for weekday “Mon”, B2: for the time “8:40-9:40”, C2: for the “Part 1”, D2: for course refer to cell C10, E2: for teacher refer to cell C11, etc. … so for each combination/slot of a weekday, time and part you have a separate line/row with the course name and teacher in the adjacent columns as cell references from the first table

Comment: It will be an one time effort, but you should be able to benefit from the pivot table function to answer your questions such as the cross-table of courses vs. teachers “automatically”. (You may want to test it e.g. by creating/referring to just the rows for Monday first; also may tweak the cell reference like this: =IF(C10="","n.a.",C10) in order to handle empty cells from the first table)

Comment: Assuming Mon-Fri, 6x 1hrs slots, Part 1..3 (+ PG?) and between 1 to 3 courses in the same “slot”: there will be 5 * 6 * 3 * 2 =  est. 180 lines to be maintained with the reference to the first table (course & teacher). Number of lines is not critical for the second table as long as there is a dedicated column for each “criteria/dimension”.

Comment: Wow! My first question on excel does not seem to be a trivial one. Thanks for your input. Will try to implement your suggestion and respond here. Thanks.

Comment: No worries. I noticed another point: Because your table allows 2 or 3 courses in the same slot (same weekday, time and part) it would be also useful adding another column e.g. “Slot” (?) with e.g. 1,2 or 3 as possible values to indicate/differentiate this as well. Probably you already know about pivot tables, if not here is a link: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576 and one example from YT (of many): https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=UsdedFoTA68 (… it shows also how your base table should look like)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You where pretty close in your attempt. You could use the following in `B70` and fill down and to the right:
`=COUNTIFS($C$10:$P$67,$A70,$C$11:$P$68,B$69)`

Comment: Wow, this is a mind-blowing use of the COUNTIFS formula that I've ever seen... thank you for sharing this!!